# No matching step binding found for this step exception

Tags: specflow

I've created a very simple feature file. When go to the definition by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd>. I get an error

> No matching step binding found for this step.

Its being thrown for my When step.

```
Feature: ItemBag



Scenario Outline: Add item to bag until 200 is reached
Given I navigate to the homepage
And I search for trainers
When I add to the bag
Then trainers are added till 200 is reached
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [What do your step definitions look like](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Details on that would really help us diagnose the problem.

Comment: I've outlined the step definitions above

Comment: Those are step *uses*, not *definitions*. I know they're not *quite* Cucumber features, but I was looking for something analogous to [these](https://docs.cucumber.io/cucumber/step-definitions/).

Comment: Can you please check ,Please do right click and then click on "Generate Steps Definitions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a Step file. It should be like this:

```
public class Steps
{
  [Binding]
  public void InavigateToTheHomepage()
  {
    this step implementation;
  }

  public void nextStep()
  {
    this step implementation;
  }
}
```

This class should contain implementation for all of your steps. After that you shouldn't receive this kind of error.